# surface area over a tetrahedron

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Compute $\int\int xy  dS$, where $S$ is the surface of the tetrahedron with sides $z=0,y=0,x=0$ and $z=1-x-y$.

I evaluated $\sqrt{3}\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}xy  dydx$ and got the result as $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{24}$.

But it doesn't match the book's answer which is $\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{24}$.

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: It is a 3D problem.You have to consider xz, yz and slant planes also.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've forgotten the tetrahedron has four sides?

You have to evaluate four integrals like yours:

$$
\int\int_S xy dS = \int\int_{S_1} xydS +  \int\int_{S_2} xydS +  \int\int_{S_3} xydS +  \int\int_{S_4} xydS \ ,
$$

where $S_1, S_2, S_3$ may be the sides $x=0, y=0 $ and $z=0$, respectively, and $S_4$ the one with $x+y+z = 1$.